# trying to display database data in html form

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to show data from the database into an html form so that the user can edit the information and update it to the datatable in wordpress.  The problem is that when I try to load the page all of the html is disappears.   The problem seems to be entering and exiting php.  I have tried moving the two } } tags after the form to the top and the html will show but no data will be inserted into the text boxes. 
Here is my code.

```
<?php get_header('settings'); ?>
<?php


$loc_id = get_query_var('id');

update_location($loc_id);


function update_location($loc_id){

    loc_update($loc_id);

    global $wpdb;
    $table_name= $wpdb-> prefix. 'dbp_tb_locations';

    if(isset($_POST['delete'] ) ){
        $wpdb->delete($table_name,
                      array(
                            'id' => $loc_id
                      )
        );    

        wp_redirect(site_url('/ts-locations-list/'));
        exit;
        }

    $DBP_result = $wpdb -> get_results("SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE id= $loc_id");
        foreach( $DBP_result as $DBP_cols){
            $id = $DBP_cols -> id;
            $name = $DBP_cols -> location_name;
            $abbreviation = $DBP_cols -> abbreviation;
            $directions = $DBP_cols -> directions;


 ?>

<div class="container p-3">
 <h3>Add / Edit Location</h3>
    <div class="card">

        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="container">
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <div class="row background">
                        <div class="col-4 outline">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-12 text-right background p-2">
                                <label class="pt-1">Name: </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-8 outline">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <div class="form-group pt-2">
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text"  name="location_name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row background">
                        <div class="col-4 outline">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-12 text-right background p-2">
                                <label class="pt-1">Abbreviation: </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-8 outline">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <div class="form-group pt-2">
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="abbreviation" value="<?php echo $abbreviation; ?>" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row background">
                        <div class="col-4 outline">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-12 text-right background p-2">
                                <label class="pt-1">Directions: </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-8 outline">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <div class="form-group pt-2">
                                        <textarea class="form-control" name="Directions" rows="10" cols="75" ><?php echo $directions ?></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row background">
                        <div class="col-4 outline">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-12 text-right background p-2">
                                <label class="pt-1">Options:</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-8 outline">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <div class="form-check pt-2 pl-3">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="customCheck">
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="customCheck">Make this location my default selection when creating classes</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row background outline">
                        <div class="col my-3 text-center">                                                         
                            <a class="btn btn-primary text-center" href="/index.php/ts-locations-list">Back       </a>
                            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary text-center">Update Location</button>
                            <button type="submit" name="delete" class="btn btn-primary text-center">Delete Location</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php

      }
}

function loc_update($loc_id){

    global $wpdb;
    $table_name= $wpdb-> prefix. 'dbp_tb_locations';

    $name = $_POST['location_name'];
    $abbreviation = $_POST['abbreviation'];
    $directions = $_POST['Directions'];

    if ( isset($_POST['submit'] ) ) {
        $wpdb->update($table_name,
                     array(
                        'location_name' => $name,
                        'abbreviation' => $abbreviation,
                        'directions' => $directions
                     ),
                    array(
                        'id' => $loc_id
                    ),
                    array(
                        '%s',
                        '%s',
                        '%s'
                    )


        );
     wp_redirect(site_url('/ts-locations-list/'));
        exit;
    }
}
?> 

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful on displaying data on the FORMS.

If you are using INPUT FIELD

value=""

You have to use htmlentities() function of PHP  to contain the the quotes and be part of inside the field.   If there is \n or "next line" on the data, you have to replace it because  input field is one liner.

Why this works?

```
cat's eye is "beautiful"
```

becomes

```
cat's eye is &quot;beautiful&quot;
```

and contained in HTML as rendered

```
VALUE="cat's eye is &quot;beautiful&quot;"
```

Comment: Thank you! So is this causing the html form to not show?